# Postfix: multiple relayhost for 2 internet lines?

Tags: postfix, smtp

Following setup is going on:

Firewall with 2 internet lines.
Postfix is running as MTA.

I have 2 ip's on the lan, 192.168.2.254 & 192.168.2.252

I would like to create the following situation:

Use both lan ip's for email handling.

- 1st lan is used for direct emailing. (relayhost="")
- 2nd lan is used to drop mails @ relayhost of the isp

The problem is that master.cf doesn't allow overriding the relayhost setting.

I have tried to use sender dependant relay host, but master.cf doesn't allow the overriding like relayhost.

Anyone an idea how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run two seperate smtpd processes, one bound to 192.168.2.254 and one bound to 192.168.2.252. See [Managing multiple Postfix instances on a single host](http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Postfix does MX resolution for the name given with "relayhost" (unless you put square brackets around it). To have multiple relay hosts, you would need a DNS name, for that multiple MX records exist (perhaps with same priorities), so that Postfix forwards mail to all of them.